# Use BigQuery in Node.js to import JSON as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine

I'm using [`@google-cloud/bigquery`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/bigquery/0.8.0/bigquery/table) and trying to import data to a table which I have JSON.

I see the [`table.createWriteStream()`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/bigquery/0.8.0/bigquery/table?method=createWriteStream) method - but I believe since that streams data it costs money, whereas methods `bq load` in the console is free.

So my two questions are:

**1**: Is using [`table.import()`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/bigquery/0.8.0/bigquery/table?method=import) the equivilent free way to load data to a table?

**2**: How can I import data that i have in a variable without having to save it to a .json file first?

Comment: How much data you want to load using free method?

Comment: lots and lots of data :)

Comment: Please define in terabytes/day then, or some dimension

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid streaming insert you should know that for load jobs there is a Daily limit: 1,000 load jobs per table per day. Streaming insert doesn't have this limit.

Streaming insert is extremely cheap, $0.05 per GB that's $50 for 1TB. Not sure how much volume you have, but usually people are not building around streaming insert because it's better suited. 
Streaming insert is the recommended way to import data, as it's scalable, it has a nice per row error message, so you can retry rows and not the full file.